# Get Neighboring Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, expression

I'm writing a function which gets neighboring (Previous and Next) entities from the database based off of a date.  I've figured out how to return the neighbors in 2 queries but I would prefer if I could pull both entities at once.

```
public interface IHasDateRange
{
    DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

public static (TEntity Previous, TEntity Next) GetNeighborsOrDefault<TEntity>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> query, JustDate startDate)
        where TEntity : class, IHasDateRange
{
    var previous = query.Where(x => x.StartDate < startDate)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    var next = query.Where(x => x.StartDate > startDate)
        .OrderBy(x => x.StartDate)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return (previous, next);
}
```

I'm would like to pull out the previous and next in a single query, preferably in a way which doesn't generate a behemoth of sql from translating an overly complex Expression.

**EDIT**
I'm thinking there is a way to do it if I remove the Where for the start date filter and calculate the distance instead I'm still stuck but I have a feeling something should work.

```
var previous = query
    .Select(x => new { 
        Entity = x,  
        Distance = DbFunctions.DiffDays(x.StartDate, startDate)
   })
    .Where(x => x.Distance != 0);
```

Note: it is assumed that every entity has a Unique startDate.

Is there a simple way I can pull out the previous and next entities in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the same as getting the two entities off of (and including) the first date before `startDate`.

```cs
query.Where(e => e.StartDate != startDate
    && e.StartDate >= query.OrderByDescending(e1 => e1.StartDate)
        .Where(e1 => e1.StartDate < startDate).Select(e1 => e1.StartDate).FirstOrDefault())
    .OrderBy(e => e.StartDate)
    .Take(2)
```

As you see, you can't avoid running two queries, although the second query now is a subquery in one main query.

In EF6, this generates a moderately complex query like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP (2)
    ...
    FROM ( SELECT 
        ...
        FROM  [dbo].[Entity] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent2].[StartDate] AS [StartDate]
                FROM [dbo].[Entity] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE [Extent2].[StartDate] < @p__linq__1
            )  AS [Project1]
            ORDER BY [Project1].[StartDate] DESC ) AS [Limit1] ON 1 = 1
        WHERE ( NOT (([Extent1].[StartDate] = @p__linq__0) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[StartDate] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = 0))) AND ([Extent1].[StartDate] >= [Limit1].[StartDate])
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[StartDate] ASC
```

I was pleasantly surprised to see EF core 3.1.3 generate a rather simple query like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP(@__p_2) ...
FROM [Entity] AS [e]
WHERE (([e].[StartDate] <> @__startDate_0) OR [e].[StartDate] IS NULL) AND ([e].[StartDate] >= (
    SELECT TOP(1) [e0].[StartDate]
    FROM [Entity] AS [e0]
    WHERE [e0].[StartDate] < @__startDate_1
    ORDER BY [e0].[StartDate] DESC))
ORDER BY [e].[StartDate]
```

Comment: Thanks I'll verify this when I get back to my computer later

Comment: Whats `Trials`?

Answer (score 1):

How about taking the before and after ones and eliminating the middle?

I believe this will still generate two separate SQL queries - one to get the `Count()` and one to get the results, but unless you want to add `ROW_NUMBER` support to EF (you can extend EF Core for it), I don't think there is a better way:

```
var previousAndNext = query.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate)
        .Skip(query.Where(x => x.StartDate < startDate).Count()-1)
        .Take(3)
        .Where(x => x.StartDate != startDate)
        .Take(2) // if startDate not in DB, just get previous and next
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I like this, Idea, I can't think of a way to do it right now, but I think there may be a crafty way to do this with select/selectMany, Join would work but I think that might make generate a query that takes longer than just selecting them individually.